# How to get attribute with namespace

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, xml-namespaces

How can I get the xsi:nil attribute value using PHP's DOMDocument (and if necessary DOMXPath)?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Rows xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Row Index="1">
    <Email xsi:nil="true"/>
  </Row>
</Rows>
```

I tried getAttribute / getAttributeNS / getAttributeNodeNS, but without success.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$element->getAttribute('xsi:nil')` ??

Comment: As said, that doesn't work..

Comment: http://3v4l.org/UmnAg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, i just tested and it works.

```
<?php
$xml=<<<EOF
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Rows xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Row Index="1">
    <Email xsi:nil="true"/>
  </Row>
</Rows>
EOF;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$emails = $doc->getElementsByTagName('Email');
var_dump($emails->item(0)->attributes->getNamedItem('nil'));
```